Angular 17 ControlValueAccessor invalid formControl not marked red
I have a custom Form Field with "ControlValueAccessor" this FormField uses [(ngModel)] to  bind it's value.
I have a FormGroup with a FormControl which defines a "minLength" Validator
The control has the correct status "INVALID" but the field is not marked as "error (red)"
Angular v17 doesn't work (https://stackblitz.com/edit/gnet2h?file=src%2FcustomFormFIeld%2FcustomFormField.component.html)
Angular v15 works (https://stackblitz.com/edit/v71qzm?file=src%2Fapp%2FcustomFormField%2FcustomFormField.component.html)

I think it's because you're combining Template and reactive forms. Try to use only reactive forms.

what do you mean with combining?
you mean the use of [(ngModel)] withing a controlValueAccessor field?

Was this resolved? As a reminder, you can answer your own question if you found the solution.
